# How to send the RSA encrypted data in " encrypted_data.bin "?

Tags: python, rsa

i use the python package " [pycryptodome](https://www.pycryptodome.org) " to send encrypted data using RSA + AES which is Hybrid cipher.

but i face a problem after encrypting the message which is the code store the encrypted data in a file called "encrypted_data.bin" which contains the data + tag + nonce. so i want to send this file to the other end so the receiver can decrypt it. and in every message i sent should i sign it and store the message in a file ? 
Here is my code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

def encrypt(msg):
   file_out = open("encrypted_data.bin", "wb")
   f = open("public_key.pem")
   recipient_key = RSA.import_key(f.read())
   f.close()
   session_key = get_random_bytes(16)

   # Encrypt the session key with the reciever's public RSA key
   cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
   file_out.write(cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key))

   # Encrypt the data with the AES session key
   cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
   ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(msg)
   print(ciphertext)
   [ file_out.write(x) for x in (cipher_aes.nonce, tag, ciphertext) ] 
   #add the cipherText to the encrypted_data.bin file
   file_out.close()

encrypt(b'This is my secret message')
```

Comment: Yes, you could just send the file, or if you have an open channel in your python application, you could also remove the file I/O operations and replace them with network (?) I/O operations or completely scratch the I/O and have the function return `cipher_aes.nonce, tag, ciphertext`...

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "should I sign it"? What are you trying to achieve? And what is the actual problem that you are facing? Are you having trouble sending or receiving the message? Decrypting the message? Or do you want to provide authenticity and integrity to the message?

Comment: @SEJPM : you mean sending each one individually and the receiver combine them together ?

Comment: @Ahmed_Salama yes, that could work as a strategy.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : "Sign it " means sending Tag+Nonce+ciphertext.. if not then should i send the ciphertext only! .

-- I'm trying to send the encrypted data which stored in a .bin file.
-- The problem is that i want to understand the process of RSA in sending encrypted data.
-- i have the "sender.py" and the "Reciever.py" but the "Reciever.py"  opens the file that was created by "sender.py" and decrypting the session then decrypting the message. but this happen because the file is already here. so if the real world how the sender send this file to be on the receiver's local storage.

Comment: If you can already decrypt the file then you can also decrypt the binary stream (even if you have to cache or save everything to file). Using stream encryption / decryption is of course more efficient. You can just send the entire file (including nonce and tag) over any binary interface, e.g. a (secure) socket or HTTP(S). If you send it over a socket you may want to prefix the size so you know that transmission has concluded (without waiting for the other party to close the socket).